# How to install ncclient correctly on CentOS7?

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, centos7, pip, openstack-neutron

I am able to install ncclient within a virtual environment on Ubuntu 14.04 server using python pip. Also need to install ncclient within virtual environment on CentOS7 Gnome Desktop platform. But I tried to install and establish communication using ncclient, I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in
<module>   File
"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ncclient/manager.py", line 142, in
connect
    return connect_ssh(*args, **kwds)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ncclient/manager.py", line 115, in
connect_ssh
    session.connect(*args, **kwds)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ncclient/transport/ssh.py", line
232, in connect
    self._auth(username, password, key_filenames, allow_agent, look_for_keys)   File
"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ncclient/transport/ssh.py", line
322, in _auth
    raise AuthenticationError(repr(saved_exception)) ncclient.transport.errors.AuthenticationError:
AuthenticationException('Authentication failed.',)
```

Also I crossverified with ssh connection (adding rsa key identity) and was able to do ssh connection to target system.

But ncclient communication is not working. Please provide some inputs or reference links.

Thanks!!

Comment: The traceback tells you exactly what is wrong. Did you read and understand it?

Comment: Thanks Michael for the quick reply..Previously I understood like ssh key identity was mismatch. Later i manually tried ssh connection with target machine and exit back and ssh connection is working fine. Even then communication via ncclient failed..Please suggest me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work around followed and being functional:
Upgrading the python pip on CentOS7 and installing pycrypto package

> $pip install --upgrade pip
>
> $pip install pycrypto

This approach provided me to establish client connection correctly.